# how do i write this exponential model as a function in R?

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

For y = B<sub>0</sub> + B<sub>1</sub>x, I can write it as `lm(y ~ x)`. However I am not sure how to write y = B<sub>0</sub>e<sup>B<sub>1</sub>x</sup> into a model function in R.

I have tried `lm(log(y) ~ x)`, `lm(y ~ exp(x))`, `lm(y ~ log(x))`, and `lm(log(y) ~ log(x))`, but I am not sure which is correct. I get different results for each model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two ways that you can do this that are actually faithful to the original statistical model (Gaussian errors with constant variance) are:

```
glm(y ~ x, family = gaussian(link = "log"), data = ...)
```

(but you'll have to exponentiate the intercept parameter) or

```
nls(y ~ b0*exp(b1*x), start = ..., data = ...)
```

(but you'll have to provide starting values in the form `list(b0 = 1, b1 = 1)` (for some sensible values).

`y = b0*exp(b1*x)` implies `log(y) = log(b0) + b1*x`, but transforming the response variable in this way will change the statistical model ... so `lm(log(y) ~ x, data = ...)` will give you *similar* but not identical answers to the preceding two recipes.

Comment: if we use nls/glm statistical model is be `E(y) = b0*exp(b1*x)` which is identical to `log(E(y)) = b0+b1*x`. But using `lm` the model is `E(log(y)) = b0 + b1*x`, which is not equivalent to the nls/glm.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're agreeing with/expanding on what I said above or ... ?  I did say they weren't equivalent ...

Comment: I totally agree with your statement. I am just confirming whether what you are saying is what i commented.

Comment: Yes, it is ....